# How do I make EastWest Hollywood Choirs perform text with Finale?

Tags: finale

I'm a Finale user and I'm considering the EastWest Hollywood Choirs virtual library, to replace the poor quality of the Garritan library's "oohs" and "ahs." I see in the system requirements ([source](https://www.soundsonline.com/hollywood-choirs)) that Finale is supported, but the WordBuilder module does not work.  I'm assuming this to mean that I would be able to use the libraries, but I wouldn't be able to make them sing the lyrics in Finale.  Essentially, I would be buying really good oohs and ahs.  I want to hear text.

I'm curious to learn what other people have tried as work-arounds before I invest.  Is there some way that I can output my music from Finale into some other sequencer, and have it tell EastWest what words to sing?

I'm an experienced (20+ years) Finale user, but brand new to EastWest and have little understanding of how their product would interface.  It would be for Windows 10 / Finale 26.

**Note** This is *not* a product recommendation request, nor a request for a product review.  I am instead wondering what a certain software is capable of.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just export the midi and then manipulate in another program?

Comment: Could I?  Is it that simple?  What other program would that be?

Comment: @nuggethead Or, as written, you could contact support for details...

Comment: Beats me, but I'm guessing one of the apps in the section above? The interesting part would be exporting the lyrics as well, and I have no idea how WordBuilder works, but in general, Sibelius/Finale are great at generating engraved music to print, but for a MIDI demo, you might do want a full-fledged DAW to do the finishing touches.